# Error while loading data from txt file to Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I am trying to transfer the contents of a txt file where all data is separated by a comma but hen I try to use the prompt:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' \
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:carat,cf:price" diamonds \
hdfs:///CA/diamonds.txt
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: invalid variable name
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.2.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.35.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.4.16/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=luan-VirtualBox
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_362
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Private Build
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: l/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-router-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-3.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2023-04-17 16:01:41,823 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=5.19.0-38-generic
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/hbase-2.4.16
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.free=40MB
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.max=965MB
2023-04-17 16:01:41,824 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.total=59MB
2023-04-17 16:01:41,826 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$14/423601841@2c2e66dc
2023-04-17 16:01:41,829 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] common.X509Util: Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2023-04-17 16:01:41,837 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2023-04-17 16:01:41,842 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2023-04-17 16:01:41,847 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2023-04-17 16:01:41,853 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:53280, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2023-04-17 16:01:41,865 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000095849a000e, negotiated timeout = 40000
2023-04-17 16:01:42,785 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2023-04-17 16:01:42,786 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2023-04-17 16:01:42,803 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$14/423601841@2c2e66dc
2023-04-17 16:01:42,804 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2023-04-17 16:01:42,805 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2023-04-17 16:01:42,806 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2023-04-17 16:01:42,807 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:53282, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2023-04-17 16:01:42,814 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000095849a000f, negotiated timeout = 40000
2023-04-17 16:01:42,917 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1000095849a000e closed
2023-04-17 16:01:42,917 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x3cd3e762-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000095849a000e
2023-04-17 16:01:42,963 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2023-04-17 16:01:42,974 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1000095849a000f closed
2023-04-17 16:01:42,974 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x610db97e-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000095849a000f
2023-04-17 16:01:43,018 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2023-04-17 16:01:43,123 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1414692256_0001
2023-04-17 16:01:43,265 INFO  [main] mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1681743703179/libjars <- /usr/local/hbase-2.4.16/libjars/*
2023-04-17 16:01:43,267 WARN  [main] fs.FileUtil: Command 'ln -s /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1681743703179/libjars /usr/local/hbase-2.4.16/libjars/*' failed 1 with: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/hbase-2.4.16/libjars/*': No such file or directory

2023-04-17 16:01:43,267 WARN  [main] mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Failed to create symlink: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1681743703179/libjars <- /usr/local/hbase-2.4.16/libjars/*
2023-04-17 16:01:43,267 INFO  [main] mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/staging/hduser1414692256/.staging/job_local1414692256_0001/libjars as file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/1681743703179/libjars
2023-04-17 16:01:43,292 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2023-04-17 16:01:43,293 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1414692256_0001
2023-04-17 16:01:43,303 INFO  [Thread-9] mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
2023-04-17 16:01:43,318 INFO  [Thread-9] mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputCommitter
2023-04-17 16:01:43,332 INFO  [Thread-9] mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
2023-04-17 16:01:43,332 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1414692256_0001_m_000000_0
2023-04-17 16:01:43,365 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2023-04-17 16:01:43,393 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/CA/diamonds.txt:0+567047
2023-04-17 16:01:43,403 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$14/423601841@2c2e66dc
2023-04-17 16:01:43,403 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2023-04-17 16:01:43,403 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2023-04-17 16:01:43,404 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2023-04-17 16:01:43,404 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:53288, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2023-04-17 16:01:43,409 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000095849a0010, negotiated timeout = 40000
2023-04-17 16:01:43,413 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapreduce.TableOutputFormat: Created table instance for diamonds
2023-04-17 16:01:43,432 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$14/423601841@2c2e66dc
2023-04-17 16:01:43,432 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2023-04-17 16:01:43,432 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2023-04-17 16:01:43,435 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2023-04-17 16:01:43,436 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:53296, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2023-04-17 16:01:43,439 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000095849a0011, negotiated timeout = 40000
2023-04-17 16:01:43,587 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1000095849a0011 closed
2023-04-17 16:01:43,587 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5b11c9ff-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000095849a0011
2023-04-17 16:01:44,024 WARN  [htable-pool-0] client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl: , BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
 on luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354, tracking started Mon Apr 17 16:01:43 IST 2023; NOT retrying, failed=2048 -- final attempt!
2023-04-17 16:01:44,261 WARN  [htable-pool-0] client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl: , BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
 on luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354, tracking started Mon Apr 17 16:01:44 IST 2023; NOT retrying, failed=2048 -- final attempt!
2023-04-17 16:01:44,303 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1414692256_0001 running in uber mode : false
2023-04-17 16:01:44,304 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2023-04-17 16:01:44,480 WARN  [htable-pool-0] client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl: , BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
 on luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354, tracking started Mon Apr 17 16:01:44 IST 2023; NOT retrying, failed=2007 -- final attempt!
2023-04-17 16:01:44,488 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask: Ignoring exception during close for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector@359194a
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 4055 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family cf does not exist in region diamonds,,1681742912754.3526ef3a36f41d286bfe23891aa21f22. in table 'diamonds', {NAME => 'carat', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}, {NAME => 'price', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
: 4055 times, servers with issues: luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.makeException(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.doFlush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:2061)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-04-17 16:01:44,494 INFO  [Thread-9] mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2023-04-17 16:01:44,494 WARN  [Thread-9] mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1414692256_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2048 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family cf does not exist in region diamonds,,1681742912754.3526ef3a36f41d286bfe23891aa21f22. in table 'diamonds', {NAME => 'carat', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}, {NAME => 'price', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
: 2048 times, servers with issues: luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:551)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2048 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family cf does not exist in region diamonds,,1681742912754.3526ef3a36f41d286bfe23891aa21f22. in table 'diamonds', {NAME => 'carat', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}, {NAME => 'price', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', IN_MEMORY => 'false', VERSIONS => '1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicBatchOp(RSRpcServices.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:45008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
: 2048 times, servers with issues: luan-virtualbox,16020,1681736516354
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BatchErrors.makeException(BatchErrors.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl.getErrors(AsyncRequestFutureImpl.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.doFlush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper.map(TsvImporterMapper.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper.map(TsvImporterMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-04-17 16:01:44,597 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1000095849a0010 closed
2023-04-17 16:01:44,597 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-127.0.0.1:2181@0x5fc61417-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000095849a0010
2023-04-17 16:01:45,307 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1414692256_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2023-04-17 16:01:45,311 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

what am I doing wrong? the diamonds.txt file looks like this:

```
0.23,326
0.21,326
0.23,327
0.29,334
0.31,335
0.24,336
...
```

I have tried variations of the same prompt but with all variations I still get the same error. I have set up the table diamonds using the prompt

**create 'diamonds', 'carat', 'price'**

Comment: There's an error message in the logs: `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family cf does not exist in region diamonds,,1681742912754.3526ef3a36f41d286bfe23891aa21f22. in table 'diamonds'`